# Target folder is there but still getting no file found error, what can be the reason?

Tags: java, maven-3, wildfly, maven-plugin, wildfly-10

I am trying to deploy the ejb jar to Wildfly 10.

I am getting the following error:

```
Oct 23, 2016 3:09:15 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
Oct 23, 2016 3:09:15 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
Oct 23, 2016 3:09:15 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
[DEBUG] Executing deployment
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.399 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-23T15:09:15-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/173M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Alpha5:deploy (default-cli) on project ejb-remote: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY: /Users/pritambanerjee/tutorials/ejb/ejb-remote/target/ejb-remote-1.0-SNAPSHOT.maven-project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Alpha5:deploy (default-cli) on project ejb-remote: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.wildfly.plugin.common.DeploymentExecutionException: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.execute(StandaloneDeployment.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.executeDeployment(AbstractDeployment.java:147)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.doExecute(AbstractDeployment.java:179)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractAppDeployment.doExecute(AbstractAppDeployment.java:70)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.execute(AbstractDeployment.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/pritambanerjee/tutorials/ejb/ejb-remote/target/ejb-remote-1.0-SNAPSHOT.maven-project
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.addContent(StandaloneDeployment.java:177)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.createDeployOperation(StandaloneDeployment.java:187)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.execute(StandaloneDeployment.java:122)
    ... 26 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The directory structure is the following:
[image]

The pom.xml for the remote is like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.baeldung.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ejb-remote</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <!-- <name>ejb-remote</name> -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Alpha5</version>

                <configuration>
                    <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
                    <port>9990</port>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- <finalName>ejb-remote</finalName> -->
    </build>
</project>
```

The pom.xml for the parent is like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.baeldung.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>ejb</name>
    <description>EJB Tutorial</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.baeldung.ejb</groupId>
                <artifactId>ejb-remote</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>ejb</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
                <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>ejb-remote</module>
        <module>ejb-client</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: May be similar issue https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/issues/33

Comment: What does your pom look like?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Hi! I updated the pom.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP-40) in the `wildfly-maven-plugin` that was fixed in 1.1.0.Alpha9. The latest version is 1.1.0.Alpha11.

If you don't want to upgrade can specify the `<filename/>` element.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Alpha5</version>

    <configuration>
        <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
        <port>9990</port>
        <filename>${build.finalName}.jar</filename>
    </configuration>

</plugin>
```